# I am ubale to install INTL extension on PHP 7.4 in my ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4, intl

My environment:

**Ubuntu**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**PHP**
PHP Version 7.4.33 (as per phpinfo() )

All I want is install the INTL extension (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) in my php

I tried this: `sudo apt install php7.4-intl`
The results is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-intl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-intl'
```

then tried `sudo apt install php7.4-dev libicu-dev`

results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-dev'
```

Tried `root@base:~# sudo apt install php7.4-xml`

results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.4-xml is already the newest version (1:7.4.33-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
root@base:~#
```

tried `root@base:~# sudo apt install php-dev`

results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-dev : Depends: php7.2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@base:~#
```

finally tried `root@base:~# sudo apt-get install -y php-intl`

results

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php7.2-common php7.2-intl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-intl php7.2-common php7.2-intl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.017 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.165 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 php7.2-common amd64 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17 [891 kB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 php7.2-intl amd64 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17 [124 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 php-intl all 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 [2.012 B]
Fetched 1.017 kB in 1s (819 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php7.2-common.
(Reading database ... 178905 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.2-common_7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-common (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.2-intl.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.2-intl_7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2-intl (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-intl.
Preparing to unpack .../php-intl_1%3a7.2+60ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-intl (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Setting up php7.2-common (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up php7.2-intl (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/intl.ini with new version
Setting up php-intl (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
root@base:~#
```

I am not sure why this installed 7.2
Now I see three folders in my `/etc/php/`

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRnrt.png)

and, still I do not see INTL in my php info

and then tried `sudo apt-get install php-intl`
shows this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-intl is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

wasted the whole day and still my phpinfo is not showing the INTL
Not sure what to do next.

Please help to install this INTL extension in my specific environment.
Is there any issue / incompatible between INTL and PHP 7.4?